# for DJANGO how can make only owner the post edit and delete

Tags: django

sorry for bad english im arabic and first im new here i wnat know how "DJANGO" how can make only owner the post edit and delete and THANK YOU

```
`class Book(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    descriptions = models.TextField(blank=True , null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='books_pic' , blank=True , null=True , default='images/genericBookCover.jpg')
    bookauthor = models.CharField(max_length=18 , null=True , blank=True)
    downloadlink = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True , blank=True)`

`def book_edit(request , id):
    update = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    form = AddBookForm(instance=update)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBookForm(request.POST or None , request.FILES or None , instance=update)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #return redirect('')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request , 'pages/edit_book.html' , context)`

`def book_delete(request , id):
    delete = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        delete.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    context = {'delete':delete}
    return render(request , 'pages/delete_book.html' , context)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always look into creating a custom decorator, but this is the quick and dirty way

```py
def book_edit(request , id):
    update = Book.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.user != update.username:
        # User Object doesn't match, redirect to Permission Denied page
        from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
        raise PermissionDenied()

    form = AddBookForm(instance=update)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBookForm(request.POST or None , request.FILES or None , instance=update)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #return redirect('')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request , 'pages/edit_book.html' , context)`
```

**Tid-bit**: Book.username actually stores the User's PK/id/row_num, not the username.. So when you compare, like above, Django is comparing the Pk- which is essentially the `User` object itself

---

**Unrelated Suggestions**:

- Change the view's arguments *away* from `id`, as that's a reserved word in Python and it makes Linters angry. Try `pk` or `row_num` instead
- Making `update|delete = Book.objects.get(id=id)` instead to `book_obj =` / `bookObj =` would make it more consistent
- Instead of `.get(id=id)` use `get_obj_or_404()`, that way it won't crash if it's not found!

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
  book_obj = get_object_or_404(Book, id=pk)
  ```